# Saving file names into an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, loops

I have a set of file names.

```
Eg: name=apple_class=1A_regis=1.txt 
    name=apple_class=1A_regis=2.txt 
    name=pear_class=1A_regis=1.txt
```

I want to be able to save all the file names that have the same 'name=apple_class=1A' into an array. That would save the first two file names into an array.

I have tried using for loop but I am still unable to get this as I have no idea how to check the filenames.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `strfind`, which returns the index where the sub-string you are looking for starts, within the string you are looking in. If the result is not empty, the string exists. In this example I compare the index to `1` and not just checking if it is not empty, to conform to your example:

```
fileName = 'name=apple_class=1A_regis=1.txt';
k = strfind (fileName, 'name=apple_class=1A');
if k==1
   % do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@Itamar Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087861/saving-file-names-into-an-array-in-matlab/7089110#7089110) answer, you would save the filenames in a cellarray of strings, apply [STRFIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html), then find the ones with matching substring:

```
filenames = {
    'name=apple_class=1A_regis=1.txt'
    'name=apple_class=1A_regis=2.txt'
    'name=pear_class=1A_regis=1.txt'
};

idx = strfind(filenames, 'name=apple_class=1A');
idx = find(~cellfun(@isempty,idx));
```

The filenames that match are:

```
>> result = filenames(idx)
result = 
    'name=apple_class=1A_regis=1.txt'
    'name=apple_class=1A_regis=2.txt'
```